# Connection Attempt Failed, Connected Party didn't Properly Respond

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, remote-access

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond. (SQL: SELECT * FROM users)

I want to connect to my remote database in my local project but when I do I get the error listed above. It works in my another database (from localhost), how can I connect my remote server database?

**database.php**

```
'mysql2' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'domain.com',
    'port' => '3306',
    'database' => 'mybd',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'options' => ['mode' => 'ssl'],
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
]
```

**Controller**

```
public function test()
{
    $users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select("SELECT * FROM users");
    dd($users);
}
```

Comment: What are you using for local development? Xampp or vm or docker

Comment: Does the remote database allow you to connect with SQL Workbench? My guess is that you have some kind of remote block enabled. If you are using Cpanel you can log in and check under `Remote MySQL` if you are hosting it yourself you can check out [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Comment: does the dbms server on your remote, listen public network or only localhost. It seems like yours is not open to public network (or lan if you're working on one)

Comment: @abdulla_malik i am using xampp

Comment: Have you been able to connect to the database from your machine with mySQl or data grip? Secondly have you tried adding these settings to your .env file? @jack-sanderson

Comment: @SuitBoyApps i have added host access

Comment: @abdulla_malik no , i don't have added those data in env file. i am assigned those data directly here

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l5si8g  http://prntscr.com/l5sicz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solutions:**

1. Try removing `SSL` from `'options'=>['mode'=>'ssl']`.
2. Disable firewall on the remote database(if you have the access) temporarily just to test. If it works then allow or add source http://localhost on your remote server.
3. Use VM or docker, configure SSL on one of these.

Comment: i am using shared hosting

Comment: Do you have ssl active?

Comment: Oh, wait. Are you saying your database is in shared hosting or your laravel application?

Comment: my laravel application are on local pc and i want to sync the online database with local pc

Comment: Your laravel application must be running on ssl otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181823/discussion-between-abdulla-malik-and-uzzal-hosen).

Answer (score 0):

- Check that the port 3306 is enabled by doing `$ telnet [IP] [PORT]`
- Add [Remote Access Host](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/databases/remote-mysql/) if using cPanel
- You would may also need to create an iptable/firewall rule to open the port 3306 with the protocol of choice [TCP/UDP]

This solved the problem for us.